# Vuetify - How to trigger method when clear a v-text-field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Is there a way to call a method while clearing a text-field with Vuetify?

```html
<v-text-field
    class="mt-2 mb-0"
    clearable
    solo
    v-model="searchQuery"
    append-icon="search"
    @click:append-outer="searchCos"
    label="Nom de compagnies ou mots-clés">
</v-text-field>
```

```js
onClear() {
  doSomethingHere()
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the `@click:clear="()"` so you can clear your text at the same time it will call the function.

Here's the example

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePmLOg?editors=1010

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent the clearing of the text. Like if I want to add a confirmation for the user prior to clearing the text? Is there an 'event' I can capture and then add preventDefault() or something like that?

Answer (score 10):

Use the `clear-icon-cb` prop. This allows you to use a custom callback function when the clear icon when clicked.

```
<v-text-field
  clearable
  :clear-icon-cb="onClearClicked">
</v-text-field>

onClearClicked () {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: :clear-icon-cb is now depreciated. now use @click:clear

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **clearableCallback**

```
<v-text-field
    ref="inputRef"
    class="mt-2 mb-0"
    clearable
    .....
 >
</v-text-field>
<v-btn text @click="clearInput">clear</v-btn>

<script>
   export default {
     ......
     methods:{
       .....
       clearInput() {
          this.$refs.inputRef.clearableCallback()
       }
    }

   }
```

Comment: This the best answer in my opinion.

Comment: Best way to do it! But use reset() instead of clearableCallback()

Answer (score 4):

Call the **reset** function of the input field like:

```html
<v-text-field ref="inputRef"></v-text-field>
<v-btn @click="clearInput">clear</v-btn>

<script>
   export default {
     methods:{
       clearInput() {
          this.$refs.inputRef.reset()
       }
     }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the clear-button to update your model-value to something specific you can also just override the clear icon:

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="myValue"
  append-icon="mdi-close"
  @clear:append="myValue = 1">
</v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, @click:clear doesn't run.
To run an action when text is typing **and** cleared, I use @input :

```
<v-text-field v-model="search" @input="sendSearch" clearable hide-details></v-text-field>
```

In my methods:

```
methods: {
  sendSearch(){
    this.$emit("send-search",this.search);
  }
}
```