# Set data to empty string on vuetify text field clearable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a `v-data-table` bound to a `search` prop, and a `v-text-field` with `clearable` set. When I clear the text field with the `clearable` icon-button, `v-text-field` sets the `search` prop to `null`, causing my computed prop to error out with:

> Cannot read property `toLowerCase()` of `null`

How can I set the `search` prop back to an empty string instead of `null` when the `clearable` icon is clicked?

*MyComponent.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field solo hide-details single-line v-model="search" clearable>
    </v-text-field>

    <v-data-table :search="search" class="mt-2" :items="myArray" hide-actions hide-headers elevation-1>
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{props.item.myItems}}</td>
      </template>    
    </v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['parameter'],
  data() {
    return {
      search: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myArray() {
      let myArray = []
      if(this.parameter) {
        myArray = this.parameter.filter((download) => {                
          return download.barcode.includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
        })
      }
      return myArray;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to check the `search` data property as a condition inside the return statement :

```
  if(this.parameter) {
      myArray = this.parameter.filter((download) => {                
            return !this.search || download.barcode.includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
        })
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, did not work. shows no data available.

Comment: try `!this.search || download.barcode.includes(this.search.toLowerCase());`

Comment: Still doesn't quite work because it does not return the values.

Comment: It is still setting the value back to null.

Comment: it should work if you set `!this.search || download.barcode.includes(this.search.toLowerCase());` or `this.search==null || download.barcode.includes(this.search.toLowerCase());`

Comment: This suggestion would make the filter incorrectly return all items regardless of the search input. The point of the filter is to collect items whose barcode **matches** the search input. Allowing `!this.search` or `this.search === null` prevents the OP's error, but also breaks the intended functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `@click:clear="clearFunction()"` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573962/vuetify-how-to-trigger-method-when-clear-a-v-text-field).

**Codepen reference:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePmLOg?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

No need to translate `search`'s `null` to empty string. Just update the computed prop to check for a truthy search value:

```js
let myArray = []

if (this.parameter && this.search ) {
  myArray = this.parameter.filter((download) => {
    return download.barcode.includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
  })
}

return myArray
```

[image: Edit Filtering items in v-data-table]